# How to create folder inside root/ of samsung galaxy tab 10.1?

Tags: android, makefile, directory, android-file

I want to create folder inside my Samsung galaxy tab10.1 like root/Myfolder.I used Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() but it gives me mnt/sdcard not root/.Anyone know how to get path of my tablet's root?

```
 String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
 File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory+"/download/", "MyPdf"); 
// folder = new File("/root/download/", "MyPdf"); 
if(!folder.exists()) {
 folder.mkdir(); 
} 
File file = new File(folder, "Read.pdf"); 
try {
 file.createNewFile(); 
} catch (IOException e1) { 
   e1.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

Comment: WOULD POST YOUR CODE THAT U TRIED AND CHECK ANDROID MANIFEAST FILE WRITE PERMISSION

Comment: String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory+"/download/", "MyPdf");
    //File folder = new File("/root/download/", "MyPdf");
          if(!folder.exists())
          {
          folder.mkdir();
          }
          File file = new File(folder, "Read.pdf");
          try {
              file.createNewFile();
          } catch (IOException e1) {
              e1.printStackTrace();
          }

Comment: @nitishpatel Which root path you want ? By default android provides the `mnt/..` as root path. AFAIK there is no another way to get the root path.

Comment: @GrIsHu I want root/.. as root path.I know mnt/.. is deafult but for tab10.1 root/ is there.whatever code I have its creating folder on my device but not on my Tab10.1 because Tab has root/.. as main folder.

Answer (score 0):

try to it

```
 File mydir = context.getDir("dir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    if(!mydir.exists)
    {
         mydir.mkdirs();
    }

Add permission in android manifest file 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

or try to it

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/MyPdf";
File dir = new File(path);
if (!dir.exists()){
    dir.mkdirs();
}
```